# How to replace a COM object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, navision, dynamics-nav

I need to develop a [COM](https://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx) object [DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Link_Library) that could replace an old one. I need this, because I don't wan't to develop an application that uses the old COM DLL. I'll make a new COM object with the same properties and methods. The main difficulty I see is [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) publication.
I don't understand the importance of some of them and where they are used, which of them I must duplicate and which might be left as different? I found out that the program which calls the COM object (in my case Navision) uses a UUID that describes the library and typelibrary. It would be nice if anyone could share experience in such a task.

Comment: If you're on NAV 2009 R2, you might want to consider making it a .NET add-in rather than a COM addin, as there is better support for .NET add-ins in NAV going forward.

Comment: Are all those UUID interface IDs for the same class, or does the COM library contain multiple classes? If the latter, how do they relate? E.g. if `object1` can create `object2`, it may use an internal method instead of using the published IID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guids are *very* important, that's what COM uses to find interfaces, classes and type libraries.  Instead of names, humans are not very good at picking guaranteed unique names.

They must exactly match or the client code won't work correctly.  You must furthermore ensure that the interfaces have the exact same methods with the exact same signatures and the exact same order.  While getting a guid wrong tends to produce a reasonable error message, getting the interface wrong almost always causes undiagnosable runtime behavior, an access violation only when you're lucky.

Comment: Are all GUID's equally important? With a reworked version of a COM object, should all GUID's match with the ones in the first version?

Comment: There's no point at all in making one of them different if this is supposed to be a drop-in replacement.